# Taylor expansion proof

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

It's pretty clear to me that in this expansion:

$$p(x) = f(0)+f'(0)x+f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2!}+f'''(0)\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$$
When I assume $x=0$, $p(0)$ is gonna be equals to $f(0)$ and all its derivatives too. But how do I know that:

if $p(0) = f(0)$ then how can I say that this is true for every $x$, in the form:
$$p(x) = f(x)$$?

Comment: Well you don't know anything about $f$ to be honest. You're manually inserting $f(0)$ as a multiplicative constant throughout all of the Taylor series. $f$ could very well be discontinuous so there's no reason for $p = f$ at all.

Comment: I'm slightly confused here; by the looks of it you are saying that $p(x) = f(0)e^x$, so I don't know how you can somehow conclude that $p(x)=f(x)$. I assume what you are trying to ask is that if two functions have the same power series, then they are equal; is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot the derivative notation

Comment: @AndrewD I've forgot to write the derivatives of $f$

Comment: This expansion doesn't imply $p(x)=f(x)$. Let $p(x) \equiv 0$ and $$f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2}, & x \ne 0, \\ 0, & x= 0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: The functions that actually do fulfill this property are called [analytic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function).